# how to handle cluster label mismatch

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

Assume I have a dataset and it has a class column: `[1,1,0,0,2,2]`. Then I use kmeans clustering as classification, and assume I got the cluster labels as: `[0,0,1,1,2,2]`.

Now, if I use `confusion_matrix` or `classification_report` to evaluate the algorithm (handling the cluster labels as classes), I should score perfectly, but in reality I won't because of the cluster label mismatch between class 0 and 1.

This is hypothetical question and I have no code. How should I handle this? I am using scikit-learn.

Comment: You sound confused; kmeans is an unsupervised algorithm, and neither `confusion_matrix` nor `classification_report` are applicable. Neither this is a *classification* problem, as your title claims.

Comment: I said, this is a hypothetical, made-up question. I understand I am not supposed to use an unsupervised algorithm when I already have classification column. I am just playing around, but I think my question is a valid one.

Comment: It is valid. But hypothetical or not, it doesn't hurt to try being accurate in the used terminology (edited title & post, pls ensure that it still describes accurately your situation).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed a clustering algorithm only attempts to divide the data into different sets, where the name of the set is irrelevant (simply cluster 1, cluster 2, ..., cluster k).

As you described above, any cluster assignment, where the cluster names are some permutation of the true classes can be returned. IN the example you supplied then the mapping between the predicted cluster names and the true cluster names (the classification column) is 0->1, 1->0, 2->2. Similarly also a result of [2,2,1,1,0,0] would be a perfect result.

Therefore, to align the clustering results with the classification column you should first apply some algorithm that will match cluster names to the classification column. This is known as the [Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), where one possible solution is to use the [Hungarian Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) to solve it. [Scipy has such an optimizer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html).

---

For the purposes of this question, we can think of the Hungarian algorithm as a way to match **each cluster name** with a **classification value**. It will find the mapping that minimizes the errors.

Graphically, think of a big confusion matrix with the true classes as columns and predictions as rows. Now, picture shifting rows and columns to try and get as much as possible a matrix with very high matchings on the diagonal and much less of diagonal. Something similar to the following picture:
[image]

In the picture above you can see that it is best to map B->B, G->G,.... The result of the Hungarian algorithm will give you such a mapping where:

- Unlike in the example picture you won't necessarily get each class mapped to itself but just some mapping.
- Similar to the example picture, there might be errors as indicated by having non zero values out of the diagonal.

Comment: It is a bit hard for me to make sense with the resources you provided.

Comment: @jaydrill - Added explanation. Is it better now?

Answer (score 1):

There is a small handy example of how can you do it.

```
import pandas as pd

def get_common_labels(labels, num_labels=3):
    check_labels = range(num_labels)
    
    labels_unique = pd.unique(labels)
    labels_to_cl = dict(zip(labels_unique, check_labels))
    
    labels_cl = list(map(labels_to_cl.get, labels))
    
    return labels_cl

y = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
predicted = [1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2]

print(get_common_labels(y) == get_common_labels(predicted))
```

Comment: Your solution seems to work real well if the predicted is 100% correct but just with different labels and your function seems to rely on that fact that prediction is perfect but different labels. But what if I happen to have some wrong predictions, then I am not sure if it still works or not. Thanks.

Comment: You are right, it works when there are objects of all classes in the predictions, and it is just an inspiration of how it should works, in practice just look at some objects in y and predictions and mapped them to the same numbers.